# Outer Join statement in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create an outer join statement in LINQ and am not having much luck. I know that Performing an outer join requires two steps:

(1)  Convert the join into a group join with into

(2)  Use DefaultIfEmpty() on the group to generate the null value you expect if the joined result set is empty.

I have been using this code as an example:

```
var query = (from p in dc.GetTable<Person>()
join pa in dc.GetTable<PersonAddress>() on p.Id equals pa.PersonId into tempAddresses
from addresses in tempAddresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, addresses.State });
```

So I tried to do this:

```
var outerJoin =

    from h in resultHours         
    join u in results on h.Key equals u.Key into outer
    from dictionary in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
```

The problem is that intellisense doesn't recognize anything in the select new {} statement.  I've tried u. and h., even dictionary.

The problem I may be running into is that I'm trying to outer join two dictionaries. It doesn't seem to like that, although this is what I was told I need to do.  I am obviously doing something wrong or not understanding something.

I need to join the dictionary results.Unit with the dictionary resultHours.Hours because my output is missing unitId fields under certain conditions.  Doing an outer join is supposed to clear this up.

Here is the code for results:

```
var results = 

    (from v in VDimUnit     
        join vf in VFactEnergyAllocation on v.UnitKey equals vf.UnitKey
        join vd in VDimGadsEvent on vf.GadsEventKey equals vd.GadsEventKey
        join vt in VDimTime on vf.TimeKey equals vt.TimeKey 
    where typeCodes.Contains(vd.GadsEventTypeCode)
    && vt.YearNum >= (year - 3) && vt.YearNum <= year       
    group vf by new {v.PlantId, v.PhysicalUnitId, v.NetDependableCapacity, v.NetMaximumCapacity, 
    vt.MonthNum} into groupItem     
    select new {groupItem.Key.PlantId, groupItem.Key.PhysicalUnitId, groupItem.Key.NetMaximumCapacity,
    groupItem.Key.MonthNum, PO_HRS = groupItem.Sum(
    x=> (float)x.AllocatedEnergyMwh / groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity),
            UO_HRS = groupItem.Sum(x=> (float)x.AllocatedEnergyMwh / groupItem.Key.NetDependableCapacity),
        Unit = groupItem.Count(), groupItem.Key}).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x);
```

Here is the code for resultHours:

```
var resultHours = 

    (from vt in VDimTime
        join vf in VFactEnergyAllocation on vt.TimeKey equals vf.TimeKey         
        join vd in VDimGadsEvent on vf.GadsEventKey equals vd.GadsEventKey
        join v in VDimUnit on vf.UnitKey equals v.UnitKey       

    group vt by new {v.PlantId, v.PhysicalUnitId, v.NetDependableCapacity, v.NetMaximumCapacity, 
        vt.MonthNum} into groupItem
    select new {groupItem.Key.PlantId, groupItem.Key.PhysicalUnitId, groupItem.Key.NetMaximumCapacity,
        Hours = groupItem.Count(), groupItem.Key}).ToDictionary(x=> x.Key.ToString(), x=> x.Hours);
```

This is presently how I have my output.  It will change after I figure out how to do the outer join.

```
var finalResults = 

    (from r in results
    orderby r.Key.MonthNum, r.Key.PlantId, r.Key.PhysicalUnitId
    select new {Site = r.Key.PlantId, Unit = r.Key.PhysicalUnitId, r.Key.MonthNum, Numerator = r.Value.PO_HRS, Denominator = 
        resultHours[r.Key.ToString()], Weight = r.Key.NetMaximumCapacity, Data_Indicator = DATA_INDICATOR, 
        Budgeted = budgetedPlannedOutageHrs, Industry_Benchmark = INDUSTRY_BENCHMARK, Comments = comments, 
        Executive_Comments = executiveComments, Fleet_Exec_Comments = fleetExecComments});
```

I'm at a loss.  The LINQ outer join examples I have found apaprently do not apply when joining dictionaries.

Comment: You are not mixing Linq2Sql and Linq2Object in the same statement are you?

Comment: @ Magnus:  To be honest with you, I'm not sure.  I don't think so.  I'll research further